# Webfont is getting cut off

Tags: fonts

This is a strange one for me, I have looked around and it isnt even that much of a problem for me.

What is happening is that "sometimes" when my page is loaded it cuts off some of the bottom or top of the font. I have no idea why but here is an example of it with a link to show that the hover is missing the top and bottom?

[image]